# How to use or implement the apple wallet kind of backend services for Android google pay?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, passkit, google-pay

We have implemented backend REST API service for creating and distributing pass for iOS(Apple Wallet). Now we are trying to implement the same for google Pay passes.And we don't much idea on this about google pay api services for this process.

Can anyone help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get started here: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api. Then walk through the starter guide.